# Why would an IT department not allow a www prefix for domains?

Tags: seo, redirects

So recently I requested a domain prefixed with *www* to be pointed to an existing site `http://example.com/`.  The IT department at my company said ". We do not allow the www prefix when dealing with sub-domains. Please do not use a www prefix."

Why would an IT department disallow this? A lot of users prefix domains with *www*, so it doesn't make sense from an SEO perspective.

Comment: Why don't you ask them why this would be the case?   Their policy is unusual.     Most websites either use the www or redirect it to the naked domain.  Without talking to your IT department, there really isn't a good way to answer this question.

Comment: "We do not allow www nomenclature when dealing with _subdomains_." - this wording seems ambiguous. Just to clarify, you're not talking about a "domain" of the form `www.domain.example.com`?

Comment: w3d, yes www.domain.example.com is the format they mean.

Comment: thanks Stephen, I asked them and they said they discussed it and that was their policy.

Answer (score 3):

From a SEO perspective, using a subdomain, www, splits up visits to the site though you can combine the data into one number. Some companies want to forgo the www since it just takes up space in advertising and is useless in a sense. Having a www, just to have one, is pointless and, should I say, old fashioned.

However, unless there is a technical reason or otherwise, they should just redirect www requests to the non-www site. It's easy to do but they must have their reasons.

Comment: see: http://no-www.org/

Comment: The notion that www splits up the visits is just plain silly. As well, the notion that adding www. takes away from advertising is also just plain silly. Www is traditionally set up as a CNAME which defeats your argument. As well, the preferred site could be non-www meaning that your argument that www. takes up room in advertisements moot. Having www simply denotes that the site is a website. Okay, things have changed and sites can just as easily be non-www which is a valid argument. In the early days, it was common that a domain would have several protocols hence the www in the first place.

Comment: @closetnoc I was just watching an old Matt Cutts video a couple of days ago where he talked about just such a thing. In fact, it was Google Webmaster Tools, years ago, that talked about letting them know which URL to prefer and just redirect one to the other for the very reason that it will otherwise split up traffic. Using www is old-fashioned. It almost always means nothing unless it's a real subdomain. It is an unnecessary thing to type, or should be. To continue to use it is silly. I was reading about the www taking up space in ads from ad agencies at least five years ago.

Comment: Rob- Please take no offense over my comment. I agree that www is not necessary. However, there are so many that expect it still and type www in the address bar (BTW- I do the opposite) and if www is not handled, the user does not get to the site. It is just plain 'ole CYA to have www and it does not actually have to be another site in reality- just an alias and the preferred non-www site can be corrected using .htaccess. Simple pimple.

Comment: @closetnoc I'm not saying to ignore it. I have a feeling we're disagreeing over something we both agree on but my/our wording is twisting us around.

Comment: Rob- You are exactly right!!

Answer (score 2):

You are right! It is tradition to have the www and therefore expected by many. Tradition that is many decades old should not be easily discarded.

At the very least, you may not be capturing the traffic that expects the www. Normally, I would say that you need to choose one or the other, www or non-www, but both should exist with one redirecting to the other. It is often better to redirect non-www to www. This answers the concern over web space, duplicate effort, and duplicate content.

Whoever created that rule likely cannot properly justify the decision without a wealth of valid reasons against to the contrary. In short, it is just a plain 'ole silly [***] thing to say and does the companies website a disservice. It misses the full potential of capturing traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are misunderstanding, or they are being too specific without explaining? A possible answer to this is because `WWW` is not a subdomain in most cases, it is a `CNAME` alias on top of an `A` record.

Other than that, it could be their "style" or something. Point to non-WWW and let the target pick up and mitigate whether it needs to be there or not. Could save a tiny shred of server response time in a non-WWW environment that way.

Comment: I wish it was a case of being specific or a misunderstanding; it seems to be a directive from on high